# Trying to login instagram in c# using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, instagram, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to login to instagram using httpclient library. I'm able to get and post request but everytime i recieve 403 Forbidden status.
initially i'm making a get request to get csrfmiddlewaretoken unique token which instagram uses for cross site request forgery by below code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string CSRFtoken = "";
        try
        {
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            cookies.Add(new Uri("https://instagram.com"), new Cookie("csrfmiddlewaretoken", CSRFtoken));
            string pagedata = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(loginURL);
            string pattern = @"csrfmiddlewaretoken""\svalue=""(.+)""";
            var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
            var m = r.Match(pagedata);
            CSRFtoken = m.Groups[1].Value;
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

after that i'm making a post request by sending csfrtoken, username and password
by

```
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("csrfmiddlewaretoken", CSRFtoken));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "abcdefg"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "1234567"));
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(loginURL, new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(responseString);
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I've read answers here and on msdn site but didn't got any working results.
tried this solution as well [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026230/login-to-instagram-programatically)

Comment: Have you tried InstaSharp?  It's been a great library for my purposes.

Comment: I know about Instasharp wrapper but it doesn't have any login functionality.