# Log in instagram via c#

Tags: c#, instagram

I want write a program in Windows Forms.I want log in in Instagram  by HttpWebResponse in c#.
I use following code to log in:

```
        HttpWebResponse Response;
        HttpWebRequest Request;
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        Uri url = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/si/fetch_headers/?challenge_type=signup&guid=");
        Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.Method = "GET";
        Request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        // Get the first response to obtain the cookie where you will find the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" value
        Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        textBox1.Text = cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value;

        string PostData = string.Format("csrfmiddlewaretoken={0}&username=seyed&password=13859", cookieContainer.GetCookies(url)["csrftoken"].Value);
        //textBox1.Text = PostData;
        HttpWebRequest req;

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
            req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            textBox1.Text = req.ContentLength.ToString();
            Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);

        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        if (s.Contains("seyed"))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Loggedin");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not");
        }
    }
```

My username and password is correct but can not log in  in it and print "Not" Message.
How fix it?

Comment: do you receive an error message ?

Comment: @ankit_sharma No

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487613/6448640

Comment: @irshadjm it do not work me.