# How to log in to Instagram via selenium, python?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Initializing the browser (I use chrome) is simple and looks like this:

```
browser = Chrome(executable_path="/Users/User/Desktop/chromedriver")
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
```

But how to refer to the field where I have to enter my credentials? Have no idea, please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login to instagram programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026230/login-to-instagram-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can via Locating Elements. Here are the examples -> [Click](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). 
Pseudo code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
```